# App is not installing when I am using CSipSimple code

Tags: android

Here I have a problem that my app was not installing.I used CSipSimple code as one module with ActionBarSherlock as library in my project. I used dependencies for CSipSimple in my app module.It getting build successful but app was not installing.If I remove dependencies for CSipSimple in my build.gradle file its working fine. But I want that CSipSimple in my project. If any body knows why this is happening please help me.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Also check [how to write a MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

This is due to difference of app signature. Uninstall and install again it will work.